Is physics limited to smooth sets?
I have come across lectures about Higher Topos Theory in mathematical physics and I am wondering about the explicit restriction to the category of smooth sets.
Why should the potentially possible laws of physics be restricted to live inside category of smooth sets? Is this category chosen because of experiments that indicate that we live in a "smooth" world? Could alternate possible laws of physics (by possible I mean internally consistent) that describe some other possible universe not constrained by relativity and QM "live inside" much less restricted set theoretical universe $V$?
Edit:
By smooth set I mean a generalized smooth space that may be probed by smooth Cartesian spaces (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+set).
Lecture by Urs Schreiber: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gr_BCr1rYVM&t=1791s

What do you mean by "smooth sets", can you define it qualitatively or mathematically? When you say "Why should the potentially possible laws of physics be restricted to live inside category of smooth sets?", do you mean the laws are elements of these sets or rather that our laws use smooth sets or something else? Please clarify the question while keeping it in line with mainstream physics. Further, consider linking and citing these lecture notes on "Higher Topos Theory".

I added what is meant by smooth set and link to the lecture.

And I mean that if there would be something fundamentally inconsistent about laws of physics using plain old sets, in other words if hypothetical alternate laws of physics could deal with worlds that are not restricted to smooth setting

Empirically, in nature, we see fractals all over the place. They aren't so common in physics texts, though.

Possible duplicates: Is the world $C^\infty$? and links therein.

There's no limit to what you are allowed to use in physics.  The only requirement is that it be empirically adequate for modeling nature.  Our current best models use vectors in Hilbert space (quantum mechanics) and fields on 4-dimensional Pseudo-Riemannian surfaces (general relativity), both of which are smooth sets.  But that doesn't mean it's impossible for some deeper theory to approximate those theories in the relevant domains using something that is not a smooth set (Stephen Wolfram for example is currently attempting such a project).
